# Creating ROC curves in R using pROC package

Tags: r, rhel, roc

I have a problem creating ROC curves in R using pROC package. The problem is detailed here:

https://superuser.com/questions/817194/installing-proc-in-rhel-6-2-and-rcpp-issue

Could you give me a hand?. Thanks!

Comment: You really shouldn't cross post to StackExchange sites. At the very least, make your question complete here so we don't have to go elsewhere to read it. Is there a reason you're using an old version of R (2.15.2 isn't exactly current)?

Answer (score 1):

You should update your R version and/or take the steps outlined here:

[How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-warning)